# Run multiple command in upstart service

Tags: upstart

I have a directory in my home folder that contains the application that I need to run on startup. 
Here is the directory structure

```
home/
 application/
    bin/
       startup.sh
```

I run this application using these commands:

```
cd application
cd bin
./startup.sh
```

How can I run these commands using the Upstart Service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upstart job should look like this:

```
chdir /home/application/bin
exec /home/application/bin/startup.sh
```

Of course, the necessary `start on` and `stop on` sections need to be added, and a description is advisable. Consult the Upstart cookbook for guidance there. (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)